# Waterline : Access populated value within a model

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I am using [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) to develop my first app. I have a [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) model as shown below.

```
//ModelA.js
module.exports = {
    attributes: {

        //more attributes

        userId: {
            model: 'user'
        },

        //more attributes
    }
};
```

I am using the model in one of my controllers as shown below.

```
  ModelA.find(options)
                .populate('userId')
                .exec(function (err, modelA) {
                    //some logic
                    //modelA.userId is undefined here
                    res.json(modelA); //userId is populated in the JSON output

                });
```

How do I get access to the populated value inside the model?

Answer (score 1):

`ModelA.find` returns array of items.

```
       ModelA.find(options)
        .populate('userId')
        .exec(function (err, results) {
            console.log(results[0].userId) //results is an array.
            //res.json(modelA); 

        });
```

Or you can use `ModelA.findOne` for a single record

Comment: This works only if it's a one-to-one association. In my case, it's a one-to-many association.

Comment: Why won't this work if it's one-to-many? I can't see any reason it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's because find return an array of records. You have to use index to access an object and then userId of that object.

```
ModelA.find(options).populate('userId').exec(function (err, recordsOfModelA) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(recordsOfModelA[0].userId)
});
```